# Select provider for location data in android

Tags: android, gps

I am using GPS_PROVIDER to get location information ,but it does not work perfectly in some places. Is there any problem when use Gps_Provider. As I know Network_Provider does not give perfect location information. Please help

Comment: gps provider will give you location update in open area only will not work when you are in building or cloudy whether.

Comment: may be this is the problem